# Django creates new cart-product instead of updating already existing object

Tags: django, django-views

In my django shop I have a adding to cart function. But if I add the same product 2 times to the cart with a different quantity, 2 different objects are created. What's wrong with my code?

here is my view

```py
def add_to_cart_view(request):
    cart = getting_or_creating_cart(request)
    product_slug = request.POST.get('product_slug')
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            new_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
                product=product,
                item_cost=product.price,
                quantity=quantity,
                all_items_cost=product.price*quantity,
            )
            if new_item.product.title == product.title:
                cart.items.add(new_item)
                cart.save()

            if not created:
                new_item.quantity += quantity
                new_item.save(force_update=True)
                cart.save()

    new_cart_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.items.all():
        new_cart_total += float(item.all_items_cost)
    cart.cart_total_cost = new_cart_total
    cart.save()

    return JsonResponse({
        'cart_total': cart.items.count()
        })
```

And here is my models

```py
class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    item_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    all_items_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product.title)


class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True)
    cart_total_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_or_create` function will try to fetch a `CartItem` with *all* the exact properties you pass it. In your case you're trying to match against `product`, `item_cost`, `quantity` and `all_items_cost`. If you pass it the same product with a different quantity, it won't match, it'll create a new `CartItem`.

Look at the [documentation of `get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). Use only `product` for the query and `defaults` for setting the value when creating a new `CartItem`:

```
new_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            product=product,
            defaults = dict(
                item_cost=product.price,
                quantity=quantity,
                all_items_cost=product.price*quantity),
        )
```

Comment: It's worked thank you so much. But how I can update quantity. For example if I already have one product in cart and click on add to cart button I want quantity updated. How can this be realized?

Comment: As far as I can see you're already doing that in your code: `if not created: new_item.quantity += quantity` does that.

Comment: I thought so too but it doesn't work. If click again just nothing happens

Comment: your line `cart.save()` should be `new_item.save()` just below. You don't need to re-save `cart` because you're not changing the `Cart` instance. Actually you can remove both `cart.save()` lines, because with `cart.items.add(new_item)` you're already saving the new relationship. `cart.save()` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

@dirkgroten provided a very good answer, you can also use unique_together option to prevent creating a duplicate entry
suppose, you've three fields name, size, brand in the Product model
and you don't want to create any new entry with the same name, size and brand
You can set it like

```
class Product:
    name = CharField(....)
    size = CharField(....)
    brand = CharField(....)
    field4 = CharField(....)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name","size","brand")
```

I personally do not entertain the use of unique_together, but it'll surely prevent from creating multiple entries in these kinds of situations from DB definition side, but you've to handle the same in the code too

Comment: Thank you for response. I will definitely consider